# Rounding to the 100 unit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I don't know if the following idea is feasible or not to generalize it, but I want to round every calculated value to the 100 unit rounding up.

example:

```
double x;
int x_final;
...
if (x<400) x_final=400;
else if (x<500) x_final=500;
else if (x<600) x_final=600;
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to round to the "closest" 100 (which means round-off)? Or round down? Or round up?

Comment: the way you do is rounding up, not round to the closest

Comment: @RonLau round up of course!

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a basic question but a proper one. It asks a reasonable question and says what he's tried.... (It might be a duplicate but that's not what votes are for...)

Comment: @jcoder Thank you for your support. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use `remquo`:

```
int
roundTo100( double x )
{
    int results;
    remquo( x, 100.0, &results );
    return 100 * results;
}
```

You'll probably need a fairly recent compiler for this, however:
the function was added to C99, and to C++ with C++11.  Depending
on the platform, you might not have it at all, or you might only
have it in `<math.h>` (but not in `<cmath>`).  If the compiler
claims C++11 support, you should have it in `<cmath>`.  But
don't believe it until you've seen it; no compiler actually
supports C++11 to any real degree yet.  On platforms where there
is support for C99 (which would include pretty much all Unix
platforms, and CygWin under Windows), it should be present in
`<math.h>`, regardless.  (But it is *not* present in Visual
Studios.)

In the absense of this function, something like:

```
int
roundTo100( double x )
{
    int results = round( x / 100 );
    return 100 * results;
}
```

might do the trick.  Beware that the two functions round
slightly differently.  The first is rounds up if the remainder
is exactly 50, the second is round to even.  The second may
potentially introduce inaccuracies due to the division (or
not—I've not analysed it sufficiently to be sure one way
or the other).

Depending on where your `x` comes from, the rounding differences
or the potential inaccuracies may not be an issue.  (If, for
example, the `x` is derived from some physical measurements with
only 3 decimal digits accuracy, the fact that it may round
"incorrectly" when `x` is distant from 50 by some 1E14 or the
like is probably irrelevant.)

Comment: Thank you so much! +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

To round up, you can use this:

```
x_final = ((int)x / 100 + 1) * 100;
```

Comment: This is not right: ((int)49 / 100 + 1) * 100 = 100, but closest 100 is 0. One has to use `round`, I think.

Comment: @utzrit I'm following the OP's code, not description. Thought that's usually more accurate.

Comment: The OP clarified his question in the comments above. Please edit your question, so that I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @urzeit I didn't change the code, but clarified words since the question has been edited as well.

Comment: I just were not allowed to remove my downvote until you changed something.

Answer (score 0):

ctry this:

```
#include <math.h>
...

x_final = ceil(x/100)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide it by 100 (ignoring the remainder) and then multiply it by 100.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val = 456;
    int r = (val / 100) * 100;
    cout << "r = " << r;
    return 0;
}
```